# What is a word for giving an answer that's not incorrect, but leaves out a bunch of information?

Tags: single-word-requests

So in my story a girl is hitchhiking east to live with her boyfriend. One of the drivers she's hitching a ride with is asking her why she's going east.

> "Willow decided she didn’t want to tell him that she was going to live
> with her dorky boyfriend, so she decided on something more ___ / she decided to give a more __ answer"
>
> 'Moving,' she answered tersely.

I'm thinking "general" or "vague", but I don't know if they're exactly describing what I'm looking for. I'm not 100% sure a phrase would work here, but I could always rework the sentence if it fits the best. I need an adjective.

Comment: Consider *evasive* or one of its synonyms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

She is being **laconic**. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/laconic):

> : using or involving the use of a minimum of words : concise to the point of seeming rude or mysterious

The emphasis is on being terse or brief, using so few words that a lot of information might be left out.

> "Willow decided she didn’t want to tell him that she was going to live with her dorky boyfriend, so she decided on something more **laconic** / she decided to give a more **laconic** answer"

Comment: Oh that's perfect! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3):

If you're OK with a word describing the *purpose* of her action, 'evasive' and 'equivocal' might work:

Merriam Webster defines [evasive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/evasive) as:

> : tending or intended to evade : equivocal
>   // *evasive* answers

and [equivocal](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/equivocal) as:

> : subject to two or more interpretations and usually used to mislead or confuse
>   // an *equivocal* statement

Otherwise, a simple option would be 'incomplete'.